# Magento 2 - How to add a custom checkbox above place order button in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, checkbox, place-order

I want to add a **custom checkbox** just above the **place order button**. The user should be allowed to click the **Place Order button** only after the **checkbox is checked**. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Magento have in-built functionality to set checkbox above place Order Button.

Login to Backend :
    Menu->Stores->Configuration->Sales->Checkout->->Checkout Options
Under that form change the value of **Enable Terms and Conditions** to YES.

After that run **php bin/magento c:f** command & see the Magic.

Comment: Hi Mansuri. This setting is to display only the terms and conditions in the checkout page. My question is to add a custom checkbox in the same page. Thanks.